# excessive creating and deleting files disadvantages

Tags: linux, filesystems, programming-languages

I have an application which is working fine at the moment,

since I'm using so many different services (`os services`) and programming languages(`python,java,C++,MySql`)  within my application,
I need to use file system to communicate among them, so  I `create and delete files` around `1000 files per minute`.

As I said system works fine at the moment but I'm worried that this approach may reduce `hard-drive` life expectancy.

just to clear things up. its a `linux(ubuntu)` system.

So my question is "***Could excessive creating and deleting files( and folders) cause problems in a long term or not?***"

Comment: how about using **dbs** to store shared data and **socket** as inter process communication?

Comment: @nafas I don't think that is the best approach, and will probably cause problems in long term

Comment: @codehx well the problem is the results can be dynamically different from one two another. Also the generated "String"s can be quite large to use for example a SQL like databases.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR yeah, this is what I'm worried about too

Comment: why dynamically different? due to using sockets? There is a way to handle that but for simplicity **I use HTTP requests** as inter process communication which is much more abstract and easy for implementation.

Comment: @codehx well imagine I'm using a program written in C++ and another one in python, I'm using these packages as black-boxes, then I use a java to wrap all these together and extract info. each black-box may fail and outputs different results based on that. since output can be huge there is no way to extract these info and send them directly to my wrapper program ( written in java) . so best approach I could think of was to use file system in/out. I know its bad, but no way I could add them all into a DB

Comment: Yes, fragmentation. One thing to consider is tuning your FS for smaller block size while creating your FS. Use 1k or 2k block size if you are creating very small files, in this way you will avoid a lot of internal fragmentation. Creating a FS with smaller block will increase the number of inodes available on the FS and should not run out inodes while creating the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unlikely, 1000 writes/minute (16/second) isn't atypical.  Check with `vmstat 1` just how many writes per second occur on a regular system that's not running your application (look at the `bo` column).  On my relatively quiet Linux box, I'll see 300-600 writes per minute.

The number of writes will be lessened by the Linux buffer cache.  Writes hit the cache first and are only flushed to disk [on a certain schedule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching).  Many operations will happen in memory alone as some of the files you are creating/deleting won't live long enough to be flushed to disk.

If you don't need your data to survive reboots, consider using tmpfs (usually on /tmp, you can also create one specifically for your purpose). That way you'll never hit disk. You'll also get a performance boost by avoiding write syncs.

Depending on your application, you may want to think about using [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) with the `mkfifo` command.  That gives you a memory-based IPC mechanism that shows up as a disk file.

Comment: that was a great comment mate, I have probably over estimated 1000 write pm . just one last question, isn't /tmp part of the hard drive? I'm looking through named pipes now, it seems it'll be much better approach to the design.

Comment: In current linuxes, /tmp is a special [magical filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) that exists only in RAM, and has no filesystem backing.

Comment: that's great, if i use /tmp folder then I have to change a minimal changes to my program